# Type *My Custom Class* has no subscript members

Tags: swift, properties

This is a question I was just about to post my finished answer to, but it seems that the author just at that moment deleted the question, possibly as the only reply was a comment saying it was not possible. I myself found the technical aspect of the question somewhat interesting, so I'm adding the same question and the answer here, in case someone else finds this of interest.

Feel free to edit this post/topic as well as its answer. Also, I've looked in the meta for guidelines regarding re-posting a deleted question in this fashion, however without finding any explicit non-advice for doing so. Please let me know if I'm in the wrong here.

---

*(Original question from SO user [Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043993/jaime))*

**Type *My Custom Class* has no subscript members**

I'm trying to do some javascript-esque code and it's blowing up.

```
class Product {

    var name : String!
    var type: String!
    var description: String!
    var taste: String!
    var picturePath: String!
    var pairings: [String]
    var similar: [String]

    init(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        let props = ["name", "type", "description", "taste", "pairings", "similar"]
        for prop in props {
            self[prop] = dict[prop]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here, or do I have to manually initialize all the properties of the class e.g.

```
if let title = dict["name"] as? String {
        self.title = title
    }
//... and so on
```

Comment: I see nothing whatever wrong with what you're doing. Asking and answering your own question is not only legal, it's encouraged; and you've explained perfectly the source of the original question and the reason for posting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: as Alex wrote in his comment to the original question, this should generally be avoided.

> It feels to weird to answer a question with "no"; even if it is
>   possible, it would either not be type-safe, or it would require so
>   much boilerplate that you'd be better off just writing the initializer
>   by hand. Swift is very often not conducive to writing Javascript-esque
>   code, since it's staticly, strongly typed.

---

Anyway, you *can* do this with the help of `Mirror` (reflecting upon self) and a tidy bit of obj-c; letting your class inherit from `NSObject`

```
class Product : NSObject {

    var varDump: AnyObject?
    var name : String?
    var type: String?
    // ...

    init(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
        super.init()

        let a = Mirror(reflecting: self).children.filter { $0.label != nil }
        for b in a {
            self.setValue(dict[(b.label ?? "")], forKey: (b.label ?? "varDump"))
        }
    }

}

var propertyInit = [String:AnyObject]()
propertyInit["name"] = "John"
propertyInit["type"] = "Human"

var a = Product(dict: propertyInit)

print(a.name ?? "Not initalized") // John
print(a.type ?? "Not initalized") // Human
```

In addition to the `NSObject` inheritance, you see that all properties that you wish to initialize in this fashion have been set to optional above. This is naturally because swift cannot know until runtime if you actually initialize these properties or not, hence yielding a compile time error if you mark them as non-optional.

Finally, again note what Alex wrote in his comment (quoted), and take this answer as a technique to *do* something, but not actually something that is to be recommended if you want to follow common Swift convention. This code will easily break at runtime if you're not very careful in you dict initialization, as you fully loose type safety.

Comment: That is simultaneously terrifying and very interesting. Sometimes I see Mirroring brought up on Swift-Evolution and I have no idea what it means, so this has been quite instructive, thanks!